# AWS S3 X-Amz-Expires with authorization headers is ignored

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I use the following code in Python to generate authorization headers for getting an object in an S3 bucket (where `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`, `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`, `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION`, and `DEFAULT_BUCKET` are all set via environment variables in another piece of code)

```py
def get_s3_headers(object_name):
    '''Get authorization headers required to access a certain object in S3.'''
    headers = _sig_v4_headers(pre_auth_headers={},
                              service='s3',
                              host=f'{DEFAULT_BUCKET}.s3.amazonaws.com',
                              method='GET',
                              path='/' + object_name,
                              query={ 'X-Amz-Expires' : '120' },
                              payload=b'')
    
    return headers


def _sig_v4_headers(pre_auth_headers, service, host, method, path, query, payload):
    
    # Define use of signature v4
    algorithm = 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256'

    now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    amzdate = now.strftime('%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ')
    datestamp = now.strftime('%Y%m%d')
    payload_hash = hashlib.sha256(payload).hexdigest()
    credential_scope = f'{datestamp}/{AWS_DEFAULT_REGION}/{service}/aws4_request'

    pre_auth_headers_lower = {
        header_key.lower(): ' '.join(header_value.split())
        for header_key, header_value in pre_auth_headers.items()
    }
    required_headers = {
        'host': host,
        'x-amz-content-sha256': payload_hash,
        'x-amz-date': amzdate,
    }
    headers = {**pre_auth_headers_lower, **required_headers}
    header_keys = sorted(headers.keys())
    signed_headers = ';'.join(header_keys)

    def signature():
        def canonical_request():
            canonical_uri = urllib.parse.quote(path, safe='/~')
            quoted_query = sorted(
                (urllib.parse.quote(key, safe='~'), urllib.parse.quote(value, safe='~'))
                for key, value in query.items()
            )
            canonical_querystring = '&'.join(f'{key}={value}' for key, value in quoted_query)
            canonical_headers = ''.join(f'{key}:{headers[key]}\n' for key in header_keys)
            print(canonical_querystring)

            return f'{method}\n{canonical_uri}\n{canonical_querystring}\n' + \
                   f'{canonical_headers}\n{signed_headers}\n{payload_hash}'

        def sign(key, msg):
            return hmac.new(key, msg.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).digest()

        string_to_sign = f'{algorithm}\n{amzdate}\n{credential_scope}\n' + \
                         hashlib.sha256(canonical_request().encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()

        date_key = sign(('AWS4' + AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY).encode('utf-8'), datestamp)
        region_key = sign(date_key, AWS_DEFAULT_REGION)
        service_key = sign(region_key, service)
        request_key = sign(service_key, 'aws4_request')
        return sign(request_key, string_to_sign).hex()

    return {
        'uri' : f'https://{host}{path}',
        'headers' : {
            **pre_auth_headers,
            'x-amz-date': amzdate,
            'x-amz-content-sha256': payload_hash,
            'Authorization': f'{algorithm} Credential={AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}/{credential_scope}, '
                            f'SignedHeaders={signed_headers}, Signature=' + signature(),
        }
    }
```

Calling get_s3_headers with a valid object key returns something similar to the following:

```json
"headers": {
    "Authorization": "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=AKIAYS3VM3EBIFL7FKE5/20220324/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date, Signature=<string of characters>",
    "x-amz-content-sha256": "e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855",
    "x-amz-date": "20220324T193132Z"
            },
"uri": "https://hotspot-storage.s3.amazonaws.com/posts/61e0dd8056716196cf357434"
```

Calling `GET` on `https://hotspot-storage.s3.amazonaws.com/posts/61e0dd8056716196cf357434?X-Amz-Expires=120` returns the correct image with no expiration errors. Changing `X-Amz-Expires` to any other value returns a "Signature not valid" exception as expected. However, I can still use the link and the headers after 120 seconds, as if `X-Amz-Expires` doesn't actually do anything. I have zero clue why this is not working, so any help would be much appreciated.

**EDIT**

Changing `X-Amz-Expires` to 0 in both the query string and Python code still allows access to the link. The expiration time always defaults to 15 minutes.

Comment: When using header authentication, the x-amz-expires header isn't parsed, it's just required since you're including it in the canonical query string.  It's only parsed and used for signed query string authentication (normally called pre-signed URLs)